# Django: Insert image in a template whose path is dynamic

Tags: django

I know I can insert an image in an html generated page based on a template using:

```
 <img src="{% static "myapp/my_image.jpg" %}" alt="Image Description">
```

The problem is I want something slightly more complex. Let's say I have an object "user" in my template with a user.first_name and a user.last_name attributes. I would like to insert an image whose path would be:

```
 <img src="{% static "myapp/{{user.first_name}}_{{user.last_name}}.jpg" %}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

This line is wrong, I get an error (Django can't parse the expression). Can someone help?

I am building kind of a organization chart with photographs, is that a proper way of including profile pictures for every member (based on the fact that the pictures should be named firstname_lastname.jpg)?

Thanks

Comment: Create the path in your view and pass it to the template...

Comment: Or write a method on the User class.

Answer (score 8):

You can do another thing:

```
<img src ="{% static 'myapp/' %}{{user.first_name}}_{{user.last_name}}.jpg" alt="Profile Picture">
```

This will work just as fine. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank u. It worked perfectly fine

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 6):

While I recommend creating the path in your view and passing it as context to your template, you can also use the [`add` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% static "myapp/"|add:user.first_name|add:"_"|add:user.last_name|add:".jpg" %}
```

You could also create a custom template tag for this. Lots of options.

Comment: Despite the other answer saying that `add` is not suitable for adding strings, this worked fine for me. Django 1.10, Python 3.5.1.

Comment: I have been searching high and low for this answer...solved my issue immediately. Also thanks to the asker for asking so clearly. I was dinged one point for my long question :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a custom filter (don't use `add`, that's not meant for adding strings).

```
<img src="{% static 'myapp/'|addstring:user.first_name|addstring:'_'|addstring:user.last_name|addstring:'.jpg' %}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

Where your [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) `addstring` could be

```
# In : templatetags/<app>_extras.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def addstring(s1, s2):
    return str(s1) + str(s2)
```

Another option is having a custom filter do all the magic & use that in img src:

```
@register.filter
def imgsrc(user):
    return 'myapp/{}_{}.jpg'.format(user.first_name, user.last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is just to set the dynamic image path. This worked for me. You can try this.

```
{% load static %}
<img src ="{% static 'images/myimage.jpg' %}" alt="My image" width="1500" height="333" id="plot" style="visibility: hidden"/>
<script>
function imageShow(){
  var name="myname";
  {% load static %}
  var filename="{% static 'images/' %}"+name+".png";
  document.getElementById("plot").src=filename;
  document.getElementById("plot").style.visibility='vsible';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
<img src ="{% static "folder name"/ %}{{user.first_name}}_{{user.last_name}}.jpg" alt="Profile Picture">
```